# How to understand the internal code of annotations

Tags: java, spring

I am working on annotations from last few years without understanding how it works internally. But now I want to understand what is the internal logic for a particular annotation.

If I take an example of @autowire or @controller, I understand where to use this annotations but I am facing difficult in finding the logic behind this annotations.

Could someone help me - **how to find the code for a particular annotation**.

Comment: Annotations are only metadata and they do not contain any business logic.

Comment: what do you mean by "the code for a particular annotation"?

Comment: @mallikarjun - I am looking into the link.

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I felt difficult to understand the functionality behind the annotation feature.

To be specific to the answer for every annotation class there will be processor, when we use the annotation the corresponding processor class will be called and will be executed. This corresponding class has to extend **AbstractProcessor**.